# How to initializing jQuery plugins with AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, initialization, route-provider, ng-view

I am new to AngularJS and I am working my way through an application which loads few jQuery plugins on page load when I load the home page of the application.

Now, in that home page I am using `ng-view` through `$routeProvider`. Now the partial templates I am embedding into `ng-view` through `$routeProvider` need some jQuery plugins to be initialized to display properly.

Could somebody help me with understanding the initialization of jQuery plugins with rendering a partial template through `ng-view`?

Comment: initialize them from directives